# Как правильно поставить timeout для пула соединений?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oracle, cx-oracle

Имеется модуль подключения к БД, пул соединений работает отлично.

Единственный минус - проблема с сетевой связностью. Пока она решается, надо при зависании соединения обрывать его. Сейчас на каком-то запросе сессия может просто зависнуть, и не понятно, пытается ли она так долго подключиться или долго получает данные или еще что-to.

Как правильно поставить *timeout* для пула соединений?

Сам пул (pool_oracl.py):

```py
from contextlib import contextmanager
from cx_Oracle import SessionPool


class OraPool:
    def __init__(self, pool_cfg):
        self.conn_pool = SessionPool(pool_cfg['USER'], pool_cfg['PASS'], pool_cfg['DSN'], pool_cfg['POOL_INIT_SIZE'],
                                     pool_cfg['POOL_MAX_SIZE'], increment=1)

    @contextmanager
    def connect(self):
        con = self.conn_pool.acquire()
        try:
            yield con
            con.commit()
        finally:
            self.conn_pool.release(con)
```

Вызов подключения:

```py
from pool_oracl import OraPool

pool = OraPool(..)
with pool.connect() as con:
    conn.cursor...
....
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Начиная с версии 18c (cx_Oracle 7.0) можно задать макс. время выполнения запроса для соединения значением атрибута [*Connection.callTimeout*](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/7.2.3/api_manual/connection.html#Connection.callTimeout).

Воспроизводимый пример:

```py
from cx_Oracle import SessionPool
import threading
from datetime import datetime as dt

pool = SessionPool('iam', 'pass', 'srv/svc', 1, 3, 1, threaded=True)

def longOp (tim, timeout):
    with pool.acquire() as conn:
        conn.callTimeout = timeout*1000
        cur = conn.cursor()
        st = dt.now ()
        print (dt.now ()-st, f"starting longop {tim} sec ...")
        try:
            cur.callproc ("dbms_session.sleep", (tim,))
        except Exception as e:
            print (dt.now ()-st, e)
        print (dt.now ()-st, "finished longop")

thd = threading.Thread (target=longOp, args=(10,3))
thd.start ()
thd.join ()
```

Вывод:

```
0:00:00.000010 starting longop 10 sec ...
0:00:03.007227 ORA-03156: OCI call timed out
0:00:03.007379 finished longop
```